# Upstairs and downstairs lights acting in unison(all on OR all off), how can I seperate them? (photos in link)

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, multiway-switch, knob-and-tube

Link to photos [here](https://imgur.com/a/imkJRSY?s=sms). `To some frustration in our home`, the current setup results in both lights acting in unison. If I want to turn on the ceiling fan/light in the foyer (1st floor), it defaults in *also* turning on the light on the second floor landing. This is problematic because the light on the second floor irritates my fiance whom is trying to sleep in the adjacent master bedroom.

There are two switches (both achieve the same result, all on or all off), so I'd like to seperate them. **I would like to have the switch at the base of the stairs control ONLY the foyer and have the switch at the top of the stairs control ONLY the second floor light**.

Extra Details, in case they matter:

- switch at the base of the stairs is a three way in a 2 gang box, (with the other gang controlling the porch lights)
- switch at the top of the stairs is a 3 way in a single gang box
- house was built in 1890 and has a mixture of modern wiring and extremely old knob & tube

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?  Is running new wiring an option at all?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Because we are renting and because more than one electrician has balked at the shoddy mismash of wiring in our home (we've had a lot of surging), I'm nervous to do anything too involved. But maybe?  Here is a link for photos. It was hard to pull them out very far without disconnecting, but let me know if you need me to disconnect for a better view. Thank you! https://imgur.com/a/imkJRSY?s=sms

Comment: Smart bulb in upstairs light fixture. Use remote to turn it off or on

Comment: @Kris that's a great idea, unfortunately it won't work. We had a similar thought and planned to just remove the bulb altogether (we don't really need the second floor landing light)... but we soon discovered the fixture has no bulbs. It is an "Integrated LED Flush Mount Light"... so the lighting is just sort of built in, somehow.

Comment: A different light fixture could be purchased that accepts a smart bulb. Very inexpensive.

Comment: Can you get us photos of the insides of the light fixture boxes as well?

Comment: what you want may not meed the requirements for stairway illumination.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, not to be dense, but are you asking for photos that show something different than the 10 photos I shared with the IMGUR link? Some of the photos show the insides of the boxes, but maybe not what you're asking me for?

Comment: @Jasen... you introduce an interesting point. Perhaps that is the reason for the odd wiring? HOWEVER, neither light actually fully illuminates the stairs. The light at the top is more for illuminating the upper hallway and the light at the bottom is actually significantly hidden from the stairs as it is under a partial ceiling for the foyer.  There are no lights directly illuminating the stairs. I'll have to do some research.

Comment: @AdventureBarbie -- yeah, the imgur link shows the insides of the switch boxes :) there are also boxes at the light fixtures themselves that may have wiring junctions in them

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel ooohhh okay, I understand now. Thanks so much for clarifying. I'll have to wait until tomorrow, so the fiancé can hold the ladder (our ceilings are 11'). Stay tuned. And thanks again!